# Select To Speak accessibility tool needs to only speak selected text in TextView

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, accessibility, screen-readers

I personally use Select To Speak a lot.  I'm currently building an Android app in Kotlin.

It pulls in a lot of external content and displays it in a TextView, I don't have control of placing or setting it specifically.  The issue is some of these TextViews are 4-5 paragraphs.  It's entirely fine for reading, but the issue is with Select To Speak.  It allows you to select a portion of the screen with a box, and it should read just what's in that box.  It does do this on browsers.  But it actually reads the entire contents of the TextView from beginning to end.  If I only want to hear the last paragraph out of 6, it's not working.  Since I'm building this app myself, I was hoping I might be able to build in a solution for this, but I've googled, and can't find anything.  I tried using HtmlCompat in my Text view hoping it might work, and I also use Markwon in many of my text views as well, but they all have the same issue.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Couldn't you write the override for selected text (highlight) and have it only read the selected text. Think copy and paste.. could you do that as well but for the STT portion

Answer (score 0):

I think that's just how `TextView`s work - I just tried *Select to Speak* out (I'm only familiar with TalkBack really) and it just seems to allow you to draw a box over an area of the screen, and any `View`s within that box get an accessibility event to describe themselves.

For a `TextView`, that just means announcing its *content description* which by default is the entire contents. (You can see this happening on the *Select to Speak* settings page, where the info box at the bottom is a single `TextView` with a couple of paragraphs, and the whole thing gets read out.)

The solution is to have multiple `TextView`s - that way they're each handled separately, and they won't all be called if the box is only drawn over a few of them. Probably the easiest way to do it is with a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` - you could probably throw one together really quickly with an `ArrayAdapter`, and pass in your text split on paragraphs. Since you're creating a standard list of text items, all the accessibility should be handled for you.

---

If you did want to get fancier, you'd have to look into the whole accessibility system, which is a little complicated, and you'd have to be able to translate touch events and their coordinates into the equivalent displayed text, and announce that. This is pretty much what your browser does, which is why it's able to treat the paragraphs separately.

And if you want to go that route, you could always display your text in a `WebView`, which is basically the core of a browser - you should get that functionality for free! If you're already trying to use HTML, that might be the best route - `TextView`s have very limited support for HTML, just some basic styling and the ability to add links.